# Macbook pro low temperature tolerance

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Can I bring my Macbook Pro car camping in temperatures that may reach -5 degrees F?  I have found a lot of information on high temperature tolerances but not on the low tolerances.

Comment: I can't offer any information on absolute temperature, but be sure when you warm it up that it happens *slowly*—otherwise condensation will form inside it, which is obviously not good!

Answer (score 2):

I just looked at the user manual for my Macbook Pro (mid-2012), and discovered this info:

**Storage Temperature:**

- -4 to 113 degrees Fahrenheit

*Operating Temperature:*

- 50 to 95 degrees Fahrenheit

According to the storage temperature, it looks like your -5 F is calling it a little too close.

[This appears to be an online copy](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/macbook_pro-15-inch-mid-2012-important_product_info.pdf) of the user manual I have.

[Look here for more manuals.](http://support.apple.com/manuals/)

Comment: @Max, My pleasure. By the way, if this answer answers your question feel free to accept it (the checkmark to the left of the answer). This benefits future visitors as they know what helped you. It also benefits you and I with reputation.